# Can elasticsearch perform on JSON structure which is highly complicated?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I was just wondering if elasticsearch would work if there is a highly nested JSON string to be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. They cannot be queried directly, instead please look at this link for how to do it properly, since you have to use a nested query to access it: [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html)